# Automatically refresh a component in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, rerender

I am working on a Blazor page for adding a new object.  The object "RepairOrder" has List of object "RepairSection".

On the page there is an area that will loop through the List "RepairOrder"."RepairSections" and show the elements:

```
   <div class="col-lg-10">
        @if (sections.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var sec in sections)
            {
                <h3>Section @sec.SectionNumber</h3>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <label for="Failure" class="control-label">Failure: </label>
                        <input for="Failure" class="form-control" bind="@sec.Failure" readonly />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>

                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" checked="@IsCApprovedChecked(sec)" />   Warranty</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="@IsWarrantyChecked(sec)" />   Repair Approved</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <label for="AdminComments" class="control-label">Admin Comments: </label>
                        <input for="AdminComments" class="form-control" bind="@sec.AdminComments" readonly />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <label for="TechComments" class="control-label">Tech Comments: </label>
                        <input for="TechComments" class="form-control" bind="@sec.TechComments" readonly />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
```

After all the current sections in the list have been added to the page, there is a button to add a new section. When the button is clicked, the function changes a bool value to true to open a modal as a dialog.  The modal contains fields to input a new section elements.

function called to open the modal:

```
protected void AddSectionCalled()
{
    _newSection = new RepairSection();
    this.isAddNew = true;
}
```

Modal Code:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" style="display:block" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-xl">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">New Repair Section</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="close" onclick="@CloseModal"><span aria-hidden="true">X</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <label for="sectionLetter" class="control-label">Section: </label>
                                <input for="sectionLetter" class="form-control" bind="@_newSection.SectionNumber" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>

                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" bind="@_newSection.Warranty" />   Warranty</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" bind="@_newSection.CustomerApproved" />   Repair Approved</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <label for="_failure" class="control-label">Failure: </label>
                                <input for="_failure" class="form-control" bind="@_newSection.Failure"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <label for="_adminComments" class="control-label">Admin Comments: </label>
                                <input for="_adminComments" class="form-control" bind="@_newSection.AdminComments" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <label for="_techComments" class="control-label">Tech Comments: </label>
                                <input for="_techComments" class="form-control" bind="@_newSection.TechComments"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary float-left" onclick="AddNewSection">Add New Section</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When the "Add New Section" button is clicked, the "_newSection" object created from the information collected in the modal is added to the "sections" list that was originally looped through when the page was loaded.

```
   private void AddNewSection()
        {
            sections.Add(_newSection);
            this.StateHasChanged();            
            this.isAddNew = false;

        }
```

as you can see I added the "StateHasChanged()" after the new section is added to the sections list. However the page does not render to display the new section.

I originally had created dummy data on the page "OnInitAsync()" event that loaded the sections list with data before it was displayed. This way I could make sure the page displayed what was in the list correctly.

How can I make the page re-render the information in the list after user adds a new object to the list?

----Edit-----

Below is the code for the entire page.  I will try and minimize this on the weekend, however there really is not a lot here.

```
 @page "/AddRepairOrder"
@using ShopLiveWebVersion2._0.Models
@using ShopLiveWebVersion2._0.DataAccess
@using ShopLiveWebVersion2._0.Services
@using ShopLiveWebVersion2._0.Data
@inject IUriHelper UriHelper
@inject RepairOrderContext context

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-10"><h1>Create New Repair Order</h1></div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<form id="AddROForm">
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label for="ControlNumber" class="control-label">Repair Order #: </label>
                <input for="ControlNumber" class="form-control" bind="@ro.ControlNumber" maxlength="15" required />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <label for="TagNumber" class="control-label">Tag #: </label>
                <input for="TagNumber" class="form-control" bind="@ro.TagNumber" maxlength="8" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label for="VIN" class="control-label">VIN: </label>
                <input for="VIN" class="form-control" bind="@ro.VIN" maxlength="18" />
                @*<small id="Chasis" class="form-text text-muted">@ro.GetChassisNumber()</small> figure out how to get chassis from vin after box looses focus*@
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label for="Make" class="control-label">Make: </label>
                <input for="Make" class="form-control" bind="@ro.Make" maxlength="30" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label for="Madel" class="control-label">Model: </label>
                <input for="Madel" class="form-control" bind="@ro.Madel" maxlength="30" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row AddRow">
            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <label for="Customer" class="control-label">Customer: </label>
                <input for="Custoemr" class="form-control" bind="@ro.Customer" maxlength="50" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label asp-for="Location" class="control-label">Vehicle Location: </label>
                <select asp-for="Location" class="form-control" bind="@ro.Location">
                    <option value="">-- Select a Location --</option>
                    @foreach (var loc in Location)
                    {
                        <option value="@loc">@loc</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label asp-for="Assigned" class="control-label">Assigned: </label>
                <select asp-for="Assigned" class="form-control" bind="@ro.Assigned">
                    <option value="">-- Select an Employee --</option>
                    @foreach (var emp in Employee)
                    {
                        <option value="@emp">@emp</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label asp-for="Status" class="control-label">Status: </label>
                <select asp-for="Status" class="form-control" bind="@ro.Status">
                    <option value="">-- Select a Status --</option>
                    @foreach (var st in Status)
                    {
                        <option value="@st">@st</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row"><div class="col-lg-1"></div><div class="col-lg-10"><hr id="Double" /></div></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                @if (sections.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var sec in sections)
                    {
                        <h3>Section @sec.SectionNumber</h3>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <label for="Failure" class="control-label">Failure: </label>
                                <input for="Failure" class="form-control" bind="@sec.Failure" readonly />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>

                            <div class="col-lg-1">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" checked="@IsCApprovedChecked(sec)" />   Warranty</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" value="@IsWarrantyChecked(sec)" />   Repair Approved</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <label for="AdminComments" class="control-label">Admin Comments: </label>
                                <input for="AdminComments" class="form-control" bind="@sec.AdminComments" readonly />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <label for="TechComments" class="control-label">Tech Comments: </label>
                                <input for="TechComments" class="form-control" bind="@sec.TechComments" readonly />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>    @*Form-group*@
</form>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <br /><br />
        <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" onclick="@AddSectionCalled">Add New Section</button>
    </div>
</div>

@if (isAddNew == true)
{
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" style="display:block" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-xl">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">New Repair Section</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="close" onclick="@CloseModal"><span aria-hidden="true">X</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <label for="sectionLetter" class="control-label">Section: </label>
                                <input for="sectionLetter" class="form-control" bind="@_newSection.SectionNumber" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>

                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" bind="@_newSection.Warranty" />   Warranty</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" bind="@_newSection.CustomerApproved" />   Repair Approved</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <label for="_failure" class="control-label">Failure: </label>
                                <input for="_failure" class="form-control" bind="@_newSection.Failure" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <label for="_adminComments" class="control-label">Admin Comments: </label>
                                <input for="_adminComments" class="form-control" bind="@_newSection.AdminComments" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <label for="_techComments" class="control-label">Tech Comments: </label>
                                <input for="_techComments" class="form-control" bind="@_newSection.TechComments" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <button class="btn btn-primary float-left" onclick="AddNewSection()">Add New Section</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@functions
{


    private RepairOrder ro;
    private RepairOrder incomingRO;
    private RepairOrderDataAccess RoData;
    private string chassis;
    private List<string> Location;
    private List<string> Employee;
    private List<string> Status;
    private FileService fileService;
    private List<RepairSection> sections;
    private bool isAddNew;

    //for new repair section modal
    private RepairSection _newSection;

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        ro = new RepairOrder();
        Location = new List<string>();
        Employee = new List<string>();
        Status = new List<string>();
        sections = new List<RepairSection>();
        isAddNew = false;
        fileService = new FileService();
        RoData = new RepairOrderDataAccess(context);
        await LoadData();

    }

    private async Task LoadData()
    {
        Location = await Task.Run(() => fileService.ReadLocation());
        Employee = await Task.Run(() => fileService.ReadEmployees());
        Status = await Task.Run(() => fileService.ReadStatus());

    }

    public string IsCApprovedChecked(RepairSection sc)
    {
        if (sc.CustomerApproved == true)
        {
            return "checked";
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public string IsWarrantyChecked(RepairSection sc)
    {
        if (sc.Warranty == true)
        {
            return "checked";
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    protected void AddSectionCalled()
    {
        _newSection = new RepairSection();
        this.isAddNew = true;
    }

    private void AddNewSection()
    {
        sections.Add(_newSection);
        this.StateHasChanged();            
        this.isAddNew = false;

    }



    private void CloseModal()
    {
        this.isAddNew = false;
    }
```

Comment: I think you should show the flow of data (_newSection) a little better. Also, what library or example did you use for the Modal comp?

Comment: Can you rewrite question as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I mean, without modal and with minimal html and minimal `RepairSection` fields.

Comment: Which component contains the method AddNewSection?

Comment: @MisterMagoo the AddNewSection() method is in the page's functions section.

Comment: Change your onclick on the Add New Section button to `onclick="@AddNewSection"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the way you have bound the `onclick` event of the button on the modal form.

you have `onclick="AddNewSection()"` 
 - writing it this way will likely be interpreted as a pure javascript call and if you inspect the DOM in your browser tools, you will likely see `onclick="AddNewSection()"` on the button.

You should have `onclick="@AddNewSection"` 
 - this way, Blazor will hook up the `onclick` event to your C# method.

Comment: You should not be using `form` elements in Blazor without at least a null method to prevent submit behaviour - if you really need `form` elements (I don't think you do) then add a null method like `onsubmit="@(()=>{})"` or `onsubmit="@DoNothing"` where DoNothing() does nothing - this will prevent default form submit behaviour.

Comment: At first i left the "()" in the onclick="@AddNewSection" - once I removed it things worked better.  Now when I hit the modal goes away and all the text (even the text in the fields for the RepairOrder disappears.  I commented out the StateHasChanged() in the AddNewSection method. Now when I click "AddNewSection" the page shows the new section for a split second and then refresh's - clearign out all the data on the page. --Just read above after I saved! I think this is my issue!!

Comment: Please update your question with specific version numbers for  .NETCore SDK , Visual Studio and the Blazor extension for VS - also include what PackageReferences you have in the csproj

Comment: Remove the `form` elements - see my comment above - they are likely causing a full page refresh

Comment: Removing the form tags form the page did the trick!!!  Thank you very much.  I am accepting this as the correct answer!

Comment: From preview 6 onward, it should now be `@onclick="@AddNewSection"`